# How to make background stretch in Android layout

Tags: android, listview, layout, background

So what I am trying to do is display background for list row element. I've created row layout and applied style :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
style="@style/product1" >
```

I've set style as:

```
<style name="product1">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/product1</item>
</style>
```

and product1.xml as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/prod1"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:dither="true"
    android:filter="false"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

where prod1.9.png is a nine patch set to be scalable top and left (so I want to have my image in right lower corner)

But the problem I am facing now is that icon is displayed in the corner while 9patch is not scaled left and up.

If instead of using style I put `android:background=@drawable/prod1` then it scales but every row get ridiculously big. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified this with your code, but the first thing that comes to mind is (assuming using 'android:background' instead of the style), instead of this on the row layout:

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

set a fixed height:

```
android:layout_height="30dp"
```

It's not as flexible, but it might suit your needs.

Comment: The hight is fine. It is the width that is to small. And obviously setting width to fix size will not work on landscape and portrait.